# Linux manage input from numpad

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-listener, input-devices

I have an extra numpad and I want to use it as macros. Is there any software for Fedora 29 that can change the input from numpad to do something like pasting text? (like "¯\_(ツ)_/¯" or "=_=")

Comment: Can you see the extra numpad key-presses as different from your regular numpad's? If they're identical, then I'd guess not (could check with `showkey` among others)

Answer (score 1):

[AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) can use a hotkey on the number pad, and it's scripts can definitely paste text, for a super basic example with this in a script:

```
keyboard.send_keys("Send these keys")
```

It's [Beginner's Guide](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Beginners-Guide) says this:

> ## What Is AutoKey and How Does It Work?
>
> It is a trigger or selection activated, automation utility program for Linux and X11. When a trigger is detected by Autokey, one of three things can happen; a script is activated, text is inserted at the cursor position or a pop-up menu is displayed allowing a script or phrase to be activated by selecting it.
>
> AutoKey scripts can literally do almost anything that can be coded as a Python program. Python scripts are user created and can be shared between users. AutoKey includes a range of sample Python scripts, and there are countless Python scripting resources on-line for learning how to write scripts.
>
> The core part of AutoKey works by sending and receiving keyboard events via the X server. It supports multiple ways of communicating with X and as such should --in theory-- work with any Western keyboard layout. (Problems are known to exist with Russian/Mandarin/Japanese languages)

Here's what it's [wiki](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki) says about it:

> In a nutshell, Autokey is a little GUI to run Python-3 scripts, specially focussing on MACRO and keypress functionality.
>
> AutoKey is not meant to be used as a general Python IDE, so it lacks debugger support and a lot more. If you wish, you can use your favourite Python IDE to edit your AutoKey scripts.

Comment: I can't find how to specify keyboard in this. (If I press "1" on my extra numpad or on my main keyboard there is no difference)

Comment: That's a bit of a problem, I know linux can tell the difference between my numberpad "1" and the regular keyboard "1", a tool like `xev` shows different keycodes or "keysym"'s. AutoKey uses key names "np_up", "np_5", "np_page_up", etc, or maybe "KP_0" through "KP_9". To set a hotkey, using the "Press to Set" picks the name well. Or I think you mean that your main keyboard numpad and the external numpad look like the same button? Does `xev` show different keycodes / keysyms for them?

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/issues/100#issuecomment-404141396) lists usable key names (after removing the `XK_` prefix), or [this link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/autokey/wikis/SpecialKeys.wiki)